# Extract database schema without security database info (Visual studio)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, dacpac

I am using VS2017 and my database runs on SQL server 2014. 
I want to create a sql database project from an existing database.
I created my sql project but I got some issues : The sql database project is created with a folder security, as shown in the screen bellow.

[image: SQL project in VS 2017]

Someone has an idea, I would just have the schema ?

Comment: If you don't want it, why not just delete the folder?

Comment: I can delete it but when I do that and I generate a bacpac from it for upgrading my database. This operation failed because it wants to remove all users presents in the security folder.

Comment: Oh right, so a dacpac doesn't have the "ignore users" option. Must admit I've always used schema compare as in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand your question:

- You have a database where some additional users have been created and
  assigned permissions / roles.
- You are creating Database Project in VS
  2017.
- Then you navigate to Project->Import->Database to import your existing database schema into the project. This imports database users into the project and you DO NOT want this to happen.

### Solution:

Do not use Import Database functionality.

Instead use Schema Compare to generate your scripts.

How to:

1. Create a new blank Database Project in VS 2017.
2. Right-Click on the
   project and select "Schema Compare...".
3. A new window will open where you need to click on "Select target..." to select your existing database.
4. **Important:** click on "Switch source and Target" button [image] to make your database a source.
5. Click "Options" button [image] to bring up "Schema Compare Options" pop up window.
6. Go to "Object Types" tab
7. Uncheck: "Users", "Database Roles", "Permissions" and any other object types you do not want to import
8. Click OK to save and close "Schema Compare Options" pop up window
9. Click on "Compare" button [image]
10. You will get a list of differences where you can further exclude individual objects:
    [image]
11. Click on "Update" button to script your objects.
12. To Save your comparison options, click on Save. It saves your comparison options only and not comparison results.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the 7. and 8. as the default setting?

Comment: You can save you comparison as a file. This saves your settings.

Comment: OK! I see. Thanks Alex.